# Salesforce php toolkit 20.0 create not working

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

Im using salesforce [PHP Toolkit 20.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit)
Here is my code, pretty simple:

```
    $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
    $mySforceConnection->createConnection(TEMPLATEPATH."/admin/salesforce/enterprise_wsdl.xml");
    $login = $mySforceConnection->login($username, $password.$securityToken);

    $sObject = new stdclass();
    $sObject->First_Name__c = 'aaaa';
    $sObject->Last_Name__c = 'vvvvv';
    $sObject->Email__c = 'test@gmail.com';

    $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject), 'Patient__c');
```

This is the soap error im getting

```
INVALID_TYPE: Must send a concrete entity type
```

I think that there is a problem with the soap request (the xml is empty)

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns1:SessionHeader><ns1:sessionId>xxxxxxx</ns1:sessionId></ns1:SessionHeader></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:create><ns1:sObjects/></ns1:create></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I think that [this is](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enterprise_Create) how the Request should look like

Has anyone encountered such a problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the toolkit 20.0 is not supported on PHP7